# Change tab color - SQL Server Management Studio Add-in

Tags: c#, ssms, add-in, envdte, vs-extensibility

I'm developing SQL Server Management Studio Add-in by EnvDTE, I want to change the color of the tab based on user setting (Something Like [TabsStudio](https://tabsstudio.com/))
in WindowCreated event like following.

```
private void WindowCreated(EnvDTE.Window window)
{
    // logic for apply color to current window's tab header.
}
```

I am not able to get tab header object of parameter window.
I tried answers from [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/091006e3-f35f-4e84-a13f-926376e9a0f9/tab-colors-change-in-extensibility?forum=vsx) but not getting child from following line.

```
System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(frameworkElement, 0);
```

Is it possible with above code or is there any other solution to do this?
Your ideas or suggestions would be a great help for me.
Thanks in advance.